# how can i get newBalance to == outstandingBalance when loop iterates through range and newBalance > 0

Tags: python

```
outstandingBalance = 1800   #declaring variables
apr = .18


interest = apr / 12         #annual interest rate
minpay = 0                #minpayment needed to payoff balance in a year
newBalance = outstandingBalance 
month = 0 #month counter

while newBalance>0:
    month = month+1             
    minpay = minpay + 10
    for i in range(1, 13):
        newBalance = newBalance * (1+interest) - minpay

        if newBalance < 0:
            break
```

so i am trying to get the newBalance to go back to the outstandingBalance value when the loop iterates through the range and newBalance is still >0 so that i can increase minpay each iteration by 10 until at 12 months newBalance <0

Comment: some example inputs and outputs to the program would be nice. At end what are you expecting? and why two different loops?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're trying to determine the minimum monthly payment needed to ensure the outstanding balance is paid off within a year, and you're approaching this by incrementing the minimum payment by 10 until the balance would be paid within a year. You can get your code up and running by moving the `newBalance = outstandingBalance` line into the loop to ensure you're restarting the calculation from the original balance each time:

```
outstandingBalance = 1800
apr = 0.18
interest = 0.18 / 12
minpay = 0

while True:
    newBalance = outstandingBalance
    minpay += 10
    for i in range(12):
        newBalance = newBalance * (1.0 + interest) - minpay
    if newBalance <= 0:
        break

print "minpay needed:", minpay
# minpay needed: 170
```

To get the exact minimum payment needed to pay off the loan in 12 months, you could use a zero-finding algorithm like Newton's method:

```
import scipy.optimize

outstandingBalance = 1800
apr = 0.18
interest = 0.18 / 12
minpay = 0

def balanceAfterYear(x, outstandingBalance, interest):
    newBalance = outstandingBalance
    for i in range(12):
        newBalance = newBalance * (1.0 + interest) - x
    return newBalance

print scipy.optimize.newton(balanceAfterYear, 0.0, args=(outstandingBalance, interest))
# 165.023987231
```